# JSON-RPC server via Python

Tags: python, json-rpc

I need to implement a JSON-RPC server like this:
http://pasha.cdemo.applicationcraft.com/service/json

This server will be accessed from jQuery and I have to use Python for writing it.

What library should I use? Can you also give me an example of using that library?

Thanks.

Comment: When you did a search here, how many questions did you find that where relevant?  Of those questions, which frameworks were mentioned most often?  Please gather a few facts and **update** your question to show which frameworks were mentioned most often on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) very easy to use (doesn't come with a predefined template engine or a database model, so it's IMO better than others when your server is producing json and is not a typical database).

Coupled with [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/) and [memcached](http://memcached.org/) can also be quite performant...

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.6 comes with json module in the standard library which allows you to effective convert Python data structures to JSON responses.

For HTTP communications and request handling, you can use Python web frameworks like Pyramid, Django or HTTP server software like Tornado. It really much depends what do you need to process in your JSON-RPC calls.